# Load Two List dynmically one after the another in android

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

Actually i have two different network calls, in which i have two different list and the first list is loading properly. i just want to add one more list. but that should load after loading the first one. please help. thanks.

Comment: You are using recycler view?

Comment: yes recycler view @RishabhSaxena

Comment: I am not clear about your question. I guess you want to merge two list which received from web service.

Comment: you have only 2 network calls ?

Comment: yes.First list which is loading properly from web service now i just want one more list to add at the bottom of the first list through the network call.@RishabhSaxena

Comment: Does each network call return different kind/type of data?

Comment: Can you show your code by editing your question. So that I can solve your query

Comment: Please provide a code snippet, what you have tried to do so!

Comment: I am having the same data but just want to repeat the network call ...same as the above call. @emilpmp

Comment: i added the code @RishabhSaxena

Comment: In that case you can initialise your recyclerview adapter using the first list(make it global) and then in the second network response, append the list to the global list and call notifyItemRangeInserted(). That should work

Comment: could you please help me with the example or code.@emilpmp

Answer (score 0):

try RxJava for it.
[Rx Java](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)

create scheduler as one array after second array